# Replace lines in File with another string

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
public class MyC{
public void MyMethod()
{
    System.out.println("My method has been accessed");
    System.out.println("hi");
}
}
```

I have an array num[]= {2,3,4}; which contains the line numbers to be completely replaced with the strings from this array

String[] VALUES = new String[] {"AB","BC","CD"};

That is line 2 will be replaced with AB, line 3 with BD and ine 4 with CD.

Lines which are not in the num[]array have to be written to a new file along with the changes made.

I have this so far.I tried several kind of loops but still it does not work.

```
public class ReadFileandReplace {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {



    try {



         int num[] = {3,4,5};

         String[] VALUES = new String[] {"AB","BC","CD"};

         int l = num.length;

         FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

         LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(br);

         FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File1.txt");

         String line;
         int count =0;

         line = br.readLine();
         count++;

         while(line!=null){
              System.out.println(count+": "+line);
              line = br.readLine();
              count++;

              int i=0;
                  if(count==num[i]){
                      int j=0;;
                    System.out.println(count);
                    String newtext = line.replace(line, VALUES[j]) + System.lineSeparator();
                    j++;
                                            writer1.write(newtext);
                  }
                  i++;
                  writer1.append(line);
              }


    writer1.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }

}


}
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
public class MyC{
AB
BC
    CD
    Sys.out.println("hi");
}
}
```

When I run the code, all lines appear on the same line.

Comment: Questions of this kind belong on StackOverflow (will most likely be migrated by the admins). But what exactly is your question? Doesn't your code work? Are the results not what you expect? Please provide error messages or samples of what acrtually happens.

Comment: See the expected output above.When i run the code, all lines appear on same line.

Comment: can u post the output you are getting?

Comment: public void MyMethod()AB
 {  System.out.println("My method has been accessed");  Sys.out.println("hi"); }}null

Note that all these charaters are on 2 lines in the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done almost, I've updated your code with a map. Check this

```
int num[] = {3, 4, 5};
String[] values = new String[]{"AB", "BC", "CD"};

HashMap<Integer,String> lineValueMap = new HashMap();
for(int i=0 ;i<num.length ; i++) {
    lineValueMap.put(num[i],values[i]);
}


FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("test1.txt");

int count = 1;
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String replaceValue = lineValueMap.get(count);
    if(replaceValue != null) {
        writer1.write(replaceValue);
    } else {
        writer1.write(line);
    }
    writer1.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    line = br.readLine();
    count++;
}
writer1.flush();
```

Comment: the new replaced lines lost their indentation.Can you fix this for me.They are not appearing in their original positions. i.e

    public class MyC{
public void MyMethod()
AB
BC
CD
}
}

Answer (score 2):

You're appending each line to the same string.  You should add the line separator character at the end of each line as well.  (You can do this robustly using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`)

Answer (score 0):

you have not appended end line character. 
writer1.append(line); is appending the data in line without endline character. Thus it is showing in one line. You might need to change it to:
writer1.append(line).append("\n");

Comment: Made the changes but still it does not replace the strings from the line specified in the num[] array with the string[]array values. Am tired of trying it.

Comment: int i=0; seems like it is reinitialising again. You should move this line to before the start of the while loop.

Comment: and value[i] in stead of value[j].

Comment: Did replace still same output.

Comment: you need to iterate throue the array.for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
     if (count == num[i]) {

Comment: System.out.println(count);
      String newtext = line.replace(line, VALUES[i])
        + System.getProperty("line.separator");
      writer1.write(newtext);
      break;
     }

Comment: }
    writer1.append(line).append(
      System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
package src;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class MainTest {


    static int i ;

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        try {



             int num[] = {3,4,5};

             String[] VALUES = new String[] {"AB","BC","CD"};

             FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("C:\\Test\\ren.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

             FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Test\\ren1.txt");

             String line;
             Integer count =0;

             line = br.readLine();
             count++;

             while(line!=null){


                 for(int index =0;index<num.length;index++){
                     if(count == num[index]){
                         line = VALUES[index];
                     }
                 }


                 writer1.write(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                 line = br.readLine();

                 count++;


                 }


        writer1.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

}
}
```